# How to pass spinner text to another activity in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have to pass data of selected index of spinner to another activity in Xamarin

```
Spinner spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner1);
var spinActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
spinActivity.PutExtra("spin",(string)spinner1.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
StartActivity (spinActivity);
```

Comment: I found solution [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36184/bind-spinner-with-value-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

I just create a sample on the similar topic.

Check it :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gZ3LiMukGdeUl6N3BXdDBhcWc